# Is it possible to automatically clean up resources at the end of scope in Guice?

Tags: java, guice

Let's say I have a `Closeable` object injected through Guice using request scope:

```
@Provides @RequestScoped
public MyCloseableResource providesMyCloseableResource(){
  return new MyCloseableResourceImpl();
}
```

Is it possible to hook-up a clean-up method that would automatically call `close()` on my resource when the scope exists, without resorting to custom scope implementation?

Looking at the custom [scope implementation guide](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/CustomScopes) on the Guice wiki, it shows that scopes should be created and cleaned up like this:

```
/**
 * Runs {@code runnable} in batch scope.
 */
public void scopeRunnable(Runnable runnable) {
  scope.enter();
  try {
    // explicitly seed some seed objects...
    scope.seed(Key.get(SomeObject.class), someObject);
    // create and access scoped objects
    runnable.run();
  } finally {
    scope.exit();
  }
}
```

I am wondering if there is way to hook-up some custom clean-up code in the `finally` of the built-in scopes (especially session and request scopes).

If it isn't possible, might there be issues that would discourage this kind of automatic clean-up?

I have found ways of achieving the same effect in servlet containers by [implementing a Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2021287/how-to-always-use-the-same-persistencemanager-within-the-same-rpc-request-on-goog) to create and clean-up a resource per request, which works great but I am curious if it is possibly with pure Guice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced a similar problem myself and finally rolled a `Disposable` interface which offers nothing but a `public void dispose()` method. I find this especially valuable for classes that register listeners somewhere and need to unregister them at a defined time. What I already had was my `AttributeHolderScope` which I [blogged about](http://www.waldheinz.de/blog/2010/07/attribute-holder-scope/) so I won't repeat that part here. The only thing that is missing now is the `AbstractAttributeHolder` which looks like this:

```
/**
 * An anstract base class for implementing the {@link AttributeHolder}
 * interface which has an implementation of the attribute related methods.
 *
 * @author Matthias Treydte &lt;waldheinz at gmail.com&gt;
 */
public abstract class AbstractAttributeHolder
        implements AttributeHolder, Disposable {

    private final Object lock = new Object();
    private transient Map<Object, Object> attributes;

    public AbstractAttributeHolder() {
        this.attributes = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
    }

    public void replaceAttributes(Map<Object, Object> newAttr) {
        synchronized (getAttributeLock()){
            this.attributes = newAttr;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAttributeLock() {
        return this.lock;
    }

    @Override
    public final void putAttribute(Object key, Object value) {
        synchronized (getAttributeLock()) {
            attributes.put(key, value);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final boolean hasAttribute(Object key) {
        synchronized (getAttributeLock()) {
            return attributes.containsKey(key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Object getAttribute(Object key) {
        synchronized (getAttributeLock()) {
            return attributes.get(key);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public final Set<Object> getAttributes() {
        synchronized (getAttributeLock()) {
            return Collections.unmodifiableSet(
                    new HashSet<Object>(this.attributes.values()));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose() {
        synchronized (this.getAttributeLock()) {
            for (Object o : this.attributes.values()) {
                if (o instanceof Disposable) {
                    final Disposable d = (Disposable) o;
                    d.dispose();
                }
            }

            this.attributes.clear();
        }
    }
}
```

This class itself implements `Disposable` so you can have nested scopes and when you dispose an outer scope, all nested scopes and, more importantly, all injected instances that implement `Disposable` get cleaned up. And to precisely answer you question: I don't think that this is possible with the `Scope` implementations provided by Guice itself, but it can be done. Everytime I look at this code I ask myself if this can't be done in a more concise way, but then it works beautifully (at least for me).

Comment: An extendible scope implementation, very good idea! So to use this with request scope, I would create `MyRequestScope` extending your scope class from the blog, wire it into the same place as the default `RequestScope` (the tricky part), do `scope.enter()` with `AbstractAttributeHolder` and make sure I call `dispose()` in the finally (or in the `exit()` of `MyRequestScope`)? If you have a nice way of integrating this could you share it (the code and/or techniques) please?

Comment: Regarding the synchronization related code, it seems unnecessary because `AttributeHolder` is always accessed from `ThreadLocal` hence one unique instance per thread. Am I missing something?

Comment: 1) I don't use this in an Servlet environment, so I am not sure how to do this properly.

Comment: 2) It depends how you use the code, I need the synchronization because for me at any given time there may be more than one Thread in a Scope so the synchronization is needed I think.

Comment: 1) Thanks! Shame about the lack of automatic clean-up in scopes. Could have been useful. Anyway, your approach seems to work well in general! The integration can be done using a servlet filter, like one described here, if anyone is interested: http://blog.yanivkessler.com/2010/06/lightweight-jdo-persistence-filter.html

Comment: 2) With regard to `synchronized(ah.getAttributeLock()){...}` inside the `scope(key,outer)` method: because you do `ah=holder.get()` just before it, it ''should'' always return a different instance per-thread (see java-doc), therefore no two threads will ever be blocked by following `synchronized` block. If `holder.get()` may return the same instance for different threads, then using `ThreadLocal` here is misleading. I guess, the only possible scenario is where `ah.getAttributeLock()` returns a shared lock object for different instances, but surely that's just making things too complicated:)))

Comment: I wrote lines about this and the synchronization here: http://waldheinz.de/2011/01/cleaning-up-resources-with-guice/ -- if you think I'm wrong about this please comment there or here, but I think some synchronization is needed, possibly even "more" than what I have now.